# how to change title in top left hand corner of sugarcrm logo?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082) of community edition sugarcrm, I need to change title in top left hand corner of sugarcrm logo to another logo picture. May I know how am I suppose to do it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

SugarCRM logo can be changed from admin panel and there is no need to do any programming or code update.

`Admin -> System Settings -> Select Logo`

I have written a blog post with screenshots that guides you to [change SugarCRM logo](http://scriptbaker.com/change-logo-sugarcrm-application/)

Answer (score 0):

The logo is located at themes/Sugar/images/dashboard.png. Replace it with a logo of your choice (default size: 28px X 28px).
The "Sugar"-directory in the path above is the name of the default-theme, and might vary depending on your current setup.

Comment: how do i replace it?do i need to delete the sugar_icon.png file first?

Comment: I already found the file for the logo, may I know how do I replace it? Do i delete it? Sorry as this is really urgent

Comment: Yes, deleted it (or rename it to something else, incase you'd change your mind in the future) and add your new logo in the same folder with the same name and pixel-size

Answer (score 0):

The logo can be changed from admin->system settings.
Here you can upload your logo.